# How is this model identified?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, identifiability

I've built a pretty complex SEM model. I know computationally it's identified (i.e. it runs in R). But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to prove it's identified. The three sufficient rule doesn't seem to apply here because there's so much going on. It's also non-recursive, so I'm struggling. Here is a path model as well as full output from Lavaan (R).

[image]

```
Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  f1 =~                                               
    Bachlr_Dgr_Prc    1.000                           
    Mdn_Hsh_I_2019    1.083    0.029   37.388    0.000
    Rural_Score      -0.637    0.024  -26.494    0.000

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Salaries ~                                          
    Mdn_Hsh_I_2019    0.630    0.041   15.187    0.000
    budget            0.431    0.023   19.023    0.000
    Mean_score       -0.687    0.068  -10.103    0.000
  budget ~                                            
    Mean_score        0.366    0.034   10.738    0.000
  Mean_score ~                                        
    f1                0.841    0.044   19.187    0.000
    Salaries          0.646    0.104    6.184    0.000
    Rural_Score       0.420    0.031   13.331    0.000
    budget           -0.514    0.069   -7.473    0.000

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
 .Rural_Score ~~                                      
   .budget            0.068    0.017    3.975    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .Bachlr_Dgr_Prc    0.336    0.017   19.608    0.000
   .Mdn_Hsh_I_2019    0.221    0.018   12.209    0.000
   .Rural_Score       0.730    0.021   34.999    0.000
   .Salaries          0.792    0.052   15.270    0.000
   .budget            0.961    0.027   35.498    0.000
   .Mean_score        1.129    0.128    8.855    0.000
    f1                0.663    0.029   22.855    0.000
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://davidakenny.net/cm/identify_formal.htm

Comment: I found that. Each of the rules alone seems fairly simple, I just can't tell which apply in this situation. And I know there are some issues with non-recursive models he doesn't address.

Comment: To clarify, if a non-recursive model converges to a solution, this does not mean the model is identified (computationally or otherwise).  It means the specific set of starting values used to estimate the solution produced a convergent model. (continuing in next comment)

Comment: If I may ask: ¿what is the need to prove mathematical convergence of such a complex model?  The identification does not inherently add any more "validity" to a solution, if the theoretical contextual framework is justifiable...even more so with non-recursive (feedback loop) models.  Said another way, one of the things you are looking for with non-recursive models is an equilibrium (which you appear to have found).

Comment: @GreggH. This is related to coursework, and our instructor likes us to be able to prove identification.

Comment: Once you have a solution from the instructor, it would be great to see how they went about proving identification for this model.